# chef knife command to show all attributes

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to display all attributes for all nodes using a single knife command.
I would specifically like to see the attributes set at the normal level

please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`knife node show $name --format json --long`. Or the shorter form `knife node show $name -Fj -l`. (if you just want normal attrs you can also use `-m/--medium`)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, depends on what you want to achieve.

You could fire this query:

```
knife search node 'name:*' -F j
```

This will fetch you all nodes and their data in JSON format mind you, but it'd be better if you can think of parameters to filter nodes depending on some attribute. Could be some attribute you set or something like `role:WEB`

Comment: Yeah, all node data will be in JSON, and you have to parse the array node-by-node. You can not get "just the attributes". This at least fetches you all attributes for all nodes.

Comment: @Jeetendra, were you able to solve it some other way? If yes, please share as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.find("*:*") {|n| puts n.normal_attrs}'
```

which will search all the nodes for the **normal attributes**

You can replace the **normal attributes** with

1. **default_attrs**
2. **override_attrs**

and finally you could replace it with **attributes** that will output in a **raw** format everything.

Comment: This worked well for me, in my case I wanted just a certain set of normal attributes keyed from a certain root normal attribute.  I used:

knife exec -E 'nodes.find("recipe:my_recipe") {|n| puts "#{n.name} #{n.normal_attrs.my_normal_attr_key_root}"}'